# Spring Security - session timeout redirection - how redirection initiated

Tags: java, spring-security, session-timeout, application-server

I was wondering, how redirection works at session timeout. In our application, on session timeout users get redirected to login page.

- What attribute of session-management cause the redirection?
- is it app-server or spring, who initiate the redirection?
- if I intercept this request, will I get a valid session or invalid session? FYI, in our case request.isRequestedSessionIdValid returns true. It means session is still valid. If I perform browser refresh still I get the valid session. Is that the correct behavior? FYI, we have session listener in place and a Filter on login page.

I wanted to understand how all this happens. Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Spring Security has very flexible and extensible set of tools. Session management is not an exception. For session timeout redirect in java based configs you should use:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
...
    .sessionManagement()
        .invalidSessionUrl("/some_redirect_URL")
...
}
```

This mechanism triggers one of implementations of `InvalidSessionStrategy` which handles the timeout exception.

Read the Spring Security documentation for more details.

You can invalidate a session in your `SessionListener`